# Dynamically add components depending on data being recieved Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I do have this working.. but I want to know if there is a better way.. because I can see how the way could potentially be a problem in the future..

Basically I have a page that brings in data and populates on the page, every time you click a 'next' button the data changes and so the page changes..

Now I have a few tools that I have set up in components and sometimes when the data says `tool === true` I show the tool component on the page so how Ive done it at the moment is like so

```
<div class="program-item">
    <div class="main">
    <div *ngFor="let asset of item?.fields?.asset" class="program-item_inner">
        <div [innerHTML]="asset.fields.textBlock"></div>

        <!-- tool -->
        <app-tool *ngIf="asset.fields.tools === 'tool'"></app-bmi-tool>
        <button *ngIf="asset.fields.tools == 'BMI Tracker'" class="full-width-btn program-item_next-button" (click)="next(item?.sys.id); child.getBmi();">CALCULATE BMI</button>

    <button *ngIf="item?.fields?.assetType !== 'tool'" class="full-width-btn program-item_next-button" (click)="next(item?.sys.id)">{{(item?.fields?.nextButtonText == null || item?.fields?.nextButtonText == undefined) ? 'NEXT' : item?.fields?.nextButtonText}}</button>
</div>
```

so basically when the data has been recieved check to see if `asset.fields.tools === tool` and then show the tool component.. this isnt a great way to do it because I have a few tools and I would have to do that for every single one

Is there another way I could do this?

Comment: you can check this out https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link of the same, https://stackblitz.com/angular/xonxgkjkrme?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts